# Ada - private record and private array not working out

Tags: arrays, private, ada, subtype

I've a small package file where I just want to define an array of couple of integer, but I want to protect it by making the type private. But after compiling and debugging I get a compilation error that I cannot solve.

Here is my code:

```
package Objet_Packing is

   type Objet_Type is private;
   subtype Objet is private;      // This is line 9

   type Tableau_Objet (<>) is private;

private                           // This is line 13

   type Objet_Type is record
      Largeur : Integer;
      Hauteur : Integer;
   end record;

   subtype Objet is Objet_Type;


   type Tableau_Objet is array ( Integer range <> ) of Objet;

end Objet_Packing;
```

And here is the error I get:

```
gcc-4.6 -c test_objet_packing.adb
objet_packing.ads:9:20: subtype indication expected
objet_packing.ads:13:01: only one private part allowed per package
gnatmake: "test_objet_packing.adb" compilation error
```

So I don't understand those two messages, and a few help would be great.

Comment: The second error is just a spurious consequence of the parser's failure to understand the first error ... seeing the word "private" twice.

Comment: @BrianDrummond: Good point; I've quoted your comment in my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have a private subtype.

To declare something as a subtype, you have to specify the base type that it's a subtype of. You can't expose the fact that it's a subtype while hiding the base type.

Either declare it visibly as a subtype of `Objet_Type`:

```
subtype Objet is Objet_Type;
```

or declare it as a private type:

```
type Objet is private;
```

In the latter case, you can define it as a derived type in the private part:

```
type Objet is new Objet_Type;
```

which means you might need to add conversions in some places. Or you can put the derived type declaration in the visible part.

On the other hand, it's not at all clear why you need two names (`Objet_Type` and `Objet`) for what are essentially the same type. What distinction are you trying to make? Perhaps a better alternative is to remove the declaration of `Objet` altogether, and just use `Objet_Type` itself directly. (Perhaps `Objet` would be a better name than `Objet_Type`, but that's a style issue.)

As Brian Drummond's comment says:

> The second error is just a spurious consequence of the parser's failure to understand the first error ... seeing the word "private" twice

Here's a modified version your package spec that declares only a single private record type. It compiles without error.

```
package Objet_Packing is
    type Objet is private;
    type Tableau_Objet (<>) is private;
private
    type Objet is record
        Largeur : Integer;
        Hauteur : Integer;
    end record;
    type Tableau_Objet is array ( Integer range <> ) of Objet;
end Objet_Packing;
```

Though since the name `Tableau_Objet` implies that it's an array of `Objet` anyway, I"m not sure why you're hiding that behind a private type (and frankly it's been long enough since I've really used Ada that I'm not entirely sure how you'd use the type `Tableau_Objet`). A more transparent alternative:

```
package Objet_Packing is
    type Objet is private;
    type Tableau_Objet is array ( Integer range <> ) of Objet;
private
    type Objet is record
        Largeur : Integer;
        Hauteur : Integer;
    end record; 
end Objet_Packing;
```

Comment: "On the other hand, it's not at all clear why you need two names (Objet_Type and Objet) for what are essentially the same type. What distinction are you trying to make?" - @Keith Thompson  
  
  
I have to use two names because the array only wants subtypes. But it doesnt seems to work properly when there is private stuff involved.

Comment: @cycourtot: "*because the array only wants subtypes*" -- I don't think that's true. Try changing the array for declaration to use the record type rather than the subtype.

Comment: @Kieth Thompson it was the first thing I've tried but I was getting compilation errors. But it could also be related to the private non-sense.